# Page well displayed in browser not when I access it from apache on localhost

Tags: html, apache, browser

I have a web page which is well displayed when I access it locally, using a web browser just opening index.html, but not well displayed when I copy it in htdocs in apache and access it.

I have the following errors in errors.log :

```
[Thu Aug 16 16:18:49 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/Program  Files/Apache2.2/htdocs/chorus-theme/images/chorus/tab-round-left3.gif, referer: http://localhost:8080/TCS/group/guest/default.htm
[Thu Aug 16 16:18:49 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/Program Files/Apache2.2/htdocs/chorus-theme/images/chorus/tab-round-right3.gif, referer: http://localhost:8080/TCS/group/guest/default.htm
[Thu Aug 16 16:18:49 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/Program Files/Apache2.2/htdocs/language, referer: http://localhost:8080/TCS/group/guest/default.htm
[Thu Aug 16 16:18:49 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/Program Files/Apache2.2/htdocs/language, referer: http://localhost:8080/TCS/group/guest/default.htm
[Thu Aug 16 16:18:49 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/Program Files/Apache2.2/htdocs/language, referer: http://localhost:8080/TCS/group/guest/default.htm
[Thu Aug 16 16:18:49 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/Program Files/Apache2.2/htdocs/language, referer: http://localhost:8080/TCS/group/guest/default.htm
[Thu Aug 16 16:18:49 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/Program Files/Apache2.2/htdocs/language, referer: http://localhost:8080/TCS/group/guest/default.htm
```

Can anyone help,

Thank you,

Nicolas Maujean

Ok I got the answer, here it is :

the error come from the fact that Apache can't interpret the following link :

The error in the log, is that the paths are not good :

rather than to have /chorus-theme, I should have ../../chorus-theme

Comment: Can you post the tag or css that's looking for tb-round-left3.gif?

Comment: the error come from the fact that Apache can't interpret the following link :

<link href="../../chorus-theme/css/main.css@browserId=firefox&t=1344590189623" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

The error in the log, is that the paths are not good :

rather than to have /chorus-theme, I should have ../../chorus-theme

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML and CSS, change your paths to

/chorus-theme/images...

and

/language....

It looks like you're trying to link to images and files in your computers filesystem, but

Comment: the error come from the fact that Apache can't interpret the following link :

<link href="../../chorus-theme/css/main.css@browserId=firefox&t=1344590189623" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

The error in the log, is that the paths are not good :

rather than to have /chorus-theme, I should have ../../chorus-theme